# SQL query for MS Access :: Retrieve column data by after some interval

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to retrieve a column data during 5 min difference for whole day, From morning 6 to 12 night from MS access DB.
e.g. I have EMP_DATA table:
[image]

The result will be,

[image]

I want a sql query which give me above result.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want row 8?

Comment: 8th row time should be 02-05-2021 06:07.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried below (ms sql) query which provide correct result,

**select *  from yourTableName where CAST(DATEPART(minute, Date_Time) as int) % 5 = 0 and CAST(DATEPART(second, Date_Time) as int) = 0 OR CAST(DATEPART(second, Date_Time) as int) = 1 order by Date_Time**

CAST(DATEPART(minute, Date_Time) as int) % 5 = 0 extract minute give minute remainder 0 and CAST(DATEPART(second, Date_Time) as int) = 0 gives 00 sec records. So the expected results will retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is complete, you can just filter on the minute and then use the `mod` operator:

```
select t.*
from t
where minute(time_value) mod 5 = 0;
```

Comment: RequestError: 'minute' is not a recognized built-in function name. Plz suggest other option.

Comment: @ViratGangurde . . . Your question is tagged MS Access and `minute` is an MS Access function:  https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/minute.php.